# Automatically Search in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to have automatic search in `TextBox`.

This code is running when I'm searching string but when I search an integer this is the error:

> Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String

I Hope You can help because i need it now.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(dataTable);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("OrderNo LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `LIKE` operator to compare numbers. I assume you want to find a matching order id:

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("OrderNo = {0}", textBox1.Text);
```

You may also want to use `int.TryParse()` to test the value in the `TextBox` first.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int orderId;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out orderId))
        return;  // not a valid number

    DataView DV = new DataView(dataTable);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("OrderNo = {0}", orderId);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
}
```

If you really want to compare the order id to a string, you must convert it first:

```
DV.RowFilter
  = string.Format("CONVERT(column3, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Thank You for helping it help but when im not typing any number my datagridview will not show any data ..